# Checking if the window is working Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, win32gui

How can I make a health check of a window by hwnd? Simply put, I need to handle an error if it happens.

The mistake in question:

[image]

I assume this can be done with Win32 libraries, but my searches haven't led to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SendMessageTimeout()` to send the `HWND` a benign message, like `WM_NULL`.  You can specify whether the function should fail if a timeout elapses, or even fail immediately if the window's thread is hung (not processing messages).

Comment: There's also the [`IsHungAppWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ishungappwindow) function, which the documentation both sells as more coherent with how the system decides, as well as tagging it as "don't use".